# XSLT Template Concat two strings

Tags: xml, xslt, join, active-directory, attributes

I will start by saying I am an xml novice. I am working on a fax server that uses an xml file to pull attributes from active directory to populate user fields. I have everything working like I want, except for the one value. For this value, I need to combine two attributes into one string that displays in the user profile of the fax server. I'm trying to combine the AD attributes telephoneNumber and ipPhone into a "888.888.8888 x254" format to display in the "PersonalVoiceNum" field. Main line followed by extension. The "x" isn't in the AD attribute, but i'd like to add that if possible. I've attempted to use concat and string-join to join them, but neither have been successful so far. I'm not saying that they wouldn't work. I just don't have the experience to format it correctly. The second bit in the code block is the two attributes I'm trying to combine. The section starting with ?xml version="1.0"? is the entire code in the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The end goal here is to populate the "PersonalVoiceNum" attribute in the xml code. "telephoneNumber" and "ipPhone" are active directory attributes that I'm pulling from. My now second section with code is showing that "PersonalVoiceNum" can be populated with either the telephoneNumber or the ipPhone attribute. I put them like that to show that you can plug either into the xsl where the ipPhone attribute is currently defined. I would like it to populate "PersonalVoiceNum" with a combination of the two. So it would look like as follows in the xml, instead of having only the telephoneNumber or the ipPhone number shown.

Solution

```
     <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='ipPhone']">
     <attr name="PersonalVoiceNum">
     <value>
     <xsl:text> 888.888.8888 x</xsl:text>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
     </value>
     </attr>
     </xsl:template>
```

.

```
 <attr name="PersonalVoiceNum">
 <value>888.888.8888 x235</value>
 </attr>
```

.

```
     <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='telephoneNumber']">
<attr name="PersonalVoiceNum">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='ipPhone']">
<attr name="PersonalVoiceNum">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>
```

Entire XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:rf="urn:rightfax-sync-schema"
xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema"
exclude-result-prefixes="rf"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Copy all nodes and attributes. -->
<xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- "userID" is a required attribute -->
<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='sAMAccountName']">
<attr name="UserID">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='objectSid']">
<attr name="AssociatedNTAccountSID">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
<attr name="RequiresNTAuth">
  <value>True</value>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='company']">
<attr name="ToCompany">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='facsimileTelephoneNumber']">
<attr name="RouteCode">
  <value>
     <!-- Get the last 4 digits of fax number, ignoring various special 
characters that might
     be found in phone numbers.  If result is Not a Number then use default 
route code instead. -->
     <xsl:variable name="cleanNumber" select="translate(node(), ' .-,()', '')"/>
     <xsl:variable name="routecode" select="substring($cleanNumber, string-length($cleanNumber)-3, 4)"/>
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string(number($routecode))='NaN'">100</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$routecode"/></xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </value>
</attr>
<attr name="PersonalFaxNum">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='l']">
<attr name="ToCityState">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='name']">
<attr name="UserName">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
<attr name="FromName">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber']">
<attr name="GeneralFaxNum">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='otherTelephone']">
<attr name="GeneralVoiceNum">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='ipPhone']">
<attr name="PersonalVoiceNum">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='legacyExchangeDN']">
<attr name="RouteInfo">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
<attr name="RouteType">
  <value>11</value> <!-- Exchange = 11 -->
</attr>
<attr name="NotifyInfo">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
<attr name="NotifyType">
  <value>17</value> <!-- Exchange = 17 -->
</attr>
<attr name="RouteFormat">
  <value>2</value> <!-- TIFF = 2 -->
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='msExchVoiceMailboxID']">
<attr name="BigVoiceMailSubscriberID">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='mail']">
<attr name="EmailAddress">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
<attr name="NotifyInfo">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
<attr name="NotifyType">
  <!-- Exchange = 17 -->
  <value>17</value>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='ObjectSid']">
<attr name="SyncGuid">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</attr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<syncRequest disabledUsers="Ignore" disabledExchangeUsers="ignore" 
xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema">
<userAddRequest source="ActiveDirectory" 
guid="010194de60143a4e878fbc12af89eae2" moveToGroup="">
<attr name="ToCompany">
  <value>Company</value>
</attr>
<attr name="RouteCode">
  <value>6600</value>
</attr>
<attr name="PersonalFaxNum">
  <value>867.510.6500</value>
</attr>
<attr name="PersonalVoiceNum">
  <value>235</value>
</attr>
<attr name="ToCityState">
  <value>Chicago</value>
</attr>
<attr name="EmailAddress">
  <value>Chris.Grif@company.com</value>
</attr>
<attr name="NotifyInfo">
  <value>Chris.Grif@company.com</value>
</attr>
<attr name="NotifyType">
  <value>17</value>
</attr>
<attr name="UserName">
  <value>Chris Grif</value>
</attr>
<attr name="FromName">
  <value>Chris Grif</value>
</attr>
<attr name="AssociatedNTAccountSID">
  <value>S-1-5-21-2106057203-4278202381-757156151-2748</value>
</attr>
<attr name="RequiresNTAuth">
  <value>True</value>
</attr>
<attr name="UserID">
  <value>Chris.Grif</value>
</attr>
<attr name="telephoneNumber">
  <value>888.888.8888</value>
</attr>
</userAddRequest>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML structure as well?

Comment: Ditto @Vinit's request: without the input XML, we can't help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. This was all that I've been working with.

Comment: @Patrick: The sample code you've posted so far is all XSL.  XSL only works when applied to input XML.  Without any input XML, we have no means of evaluating whether the XSL rules here are correct, or what they will do.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Okay, I believe I found the actual XML part of it all. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I have edited the main post at the end of the original code.

Comment: Please minimize the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem, and include the expected output. Note also that there is no `ipPhone` node in your input, so that part is not clear.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Apologies. I'm not used to posting on here. Thank you for formatting the code as well. I will modify my post with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I'm trying to combine the AD attributes telephoneNumber and ipPhone into a "888.888.8888 x254" format to display in the "PersonalVoiceNum" field.
```

You could do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='telephoneNumber']">
  <attr name="PersonalVoiceNum">
    <value>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text> x</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../rf:attr[@name='ipPhone']"/>
    </value>
  </attr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='ipPhone']"/>
```

Comment: That did not produce anything. If the code isn't valid (in it's eyes), it simply doesn't sync the user from AD to the server.

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "sync the user from AD to the server". You need to adapt my code to fit in your stylesheet, and if you can't get it to work, we can't help you unless you give more details of your input and your stylesheet. As others have commented, you've given us incomplete information so inevitably my answer will be incomplete.

Comment: My apologies. I shouldn't assume it's a copy paste job. I was able to adapt it and get it working, so thank you for that. It turned out to be fairly simple. I'll post my code above.